# Trying to sending sms to India mobile through AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

My use case is to send sms to India mobile through AWS SNS. I created subscriber and selected protocol as sms. For endpoint I gave my mobile number - it accepts and created subscription.

I created topic for the subscription to send sms to my mobile number. It shows sent message but I didn't receive any message from the topic?

How to send sms to Indian mobile number in AWS SNS?

Please help me!!! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Having worked on a lot of SMS applications with consumers in every country, I can telll you India is one of those places that are often difficult to get the SMS's delivered.

From the Twilio website (but applies to any SMS provider):

> Limitations sending SMS messages to Indian mobile devices SMS messages
>   entering into India are categorized as “Transactional” or
>   “Promotional”. By default, all SMS messages sent from Twilio phone
>   numbers are categorized as “Promotional” and are subject to the
>   following limitations:
>
> 1. They cannot be sent to any phone number in India’s Do Not Call Registry
>
> If you’ve been having trouble sending SMS messages to an Indian
>   number, see if that number is registered on the National Do Not Call
>   Registry.
>
> If the owner of the phone number wishes to start receiving SMS
>   messages from Twilio, they can update the DNC settings by following
>   the instructions on this website.
>
> 2. The sender IDs are changed to the format “XX-NNNNNN”
>
> The sender IDs are altered before SMS messages are delivered to end
>   users. End users are very likely to see a sender ID composed of 2
>   letters followed by 6 numbers instead of the Sender ID you specified.
>   Due to the sender ID change, SMS recipients are unable to send a reply
>   back to your Twilio phone number.
>
> 3. They are only delivered between the hours of 9 A.M. and 9 P.M. local Indian time
>
> If you’ve been seeing delivery delays when sending to Indian numbers,
>   make sure you are making the requests during the operational hours of
>   9 A.M. to 9 P.M., as overnight messages are likely to be cached until
>   the next day.
>
> 4. No more than one message every 20 minutes from the same Sender ID to the same destination number with the same message body
>
> This is to to avoid potential SMS flooding. If you have a need to send
>   identical messages more frequently than this rate, consider getting
>   more Twilio numbers.
>
> Please note that the above limitations are regulations set up by
>   Indian government. If the above still doesn’t explain the issue you’re
>   running into when sending SMS to India, please write to us, we would
>   love to help.

Comment: Thanks. Is any alternate way to use AWS SNS to send sms immediately once topic is triggered.