# AWS SNS Endpoint not sending sms after 9 pm IST

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk

I am using AWS SDK to send the sms to the mobile number for sending OTP through the SMS.

The Issue here I am facing is the SMS are only being sent during the day time according to Indian Standard Time (9 am to 9pm). If I try to send SMS request to the AWS SNS endpoint after 9 pm, then it will send the message after 9 am the next day.

The code is as below.

```java
String ACCESS_KEY = env.getProperty("aws.access.key");
String SECRET_KEY = env.getProperty("aws.secret.access.key");

// Above we get the access and secret access key as credentials for the user.

String otp = getRandomNumberString();  // generates an OTP number of 4 digit

AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, 
         SECRET_KEY));

String message = "Your Connect OTP for Login/Signup is: " + otp
    + ".\nNote: Please DO NOT SHARE THIS OTP with anyone.\nThanks";
String phoneNumber = "+91" + String.valueOf(mobile); // Ex: +91XXX4374XX
String messageID = sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber);

// The definition of method named "sendSMSMessage" as above is written below in next code block
```

```java
//definition of method named "sendSMSMessage"

public static String sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String message, String phoneNumber) {
    PublishResult result = snsClient
        .publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(message).withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber));
    return result.getMessageId();
}
```

Comment: It looks like nothing with the code, but the list item #3 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561149/4636715

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of SMS that you can send.

-**Promotional Messages**
-**Transaction Messages**

*Promotional messages* are like Advertisment. These Messges will not be delivered to DND numbers and also these messages can only be delivered between 9Am to 9PM as per NCPR guidelines.

*Transaction Messages* are sent for Transaction purpose  like sending OTP and sending Payment confirmation. These messages can be delivered to any number  24/7.

So the problem is you need to change your SMS type to Transaction SMS